# Microsoft Store UWP App Durable Addon (Subscription) unable to purchase

Tags: uwp, in-app-purchase, store, subscription, add-on

I am published a free UWP app where I would like to use Subscription Addons. The app and addons are submitted successfully into the MS Store.

I tried the following approaches with my personal account both in development mode and the released app:

```
    //var result1 = await Subscription_Standard_01month.Skus[0].RequestPurchaseAsync();
    //var result2 = await Subscription_Standard_01month.Skus[1].RequestPurchaseAsync();
    //var result3 = await Subscription_Standard_01month.RequestPurchaseAsync();
    var result4 = await context.RequestPurchaseAsync(subscriptionstoreid);
```

All the results are: StorePurchaseStatus.NotPurchased

After clicking on Purchase there is a popup shows up which is loading a bit and closes automatically.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I've replied to you in MSDN. Please check that.

Comment: Thanks, let's continue over there.

Comment: Sure, please check my reply there.

Comment: Any update? I have same issue.